# How to assign reactiveValues() Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I want to use `reactiveValues()` in my shiny app but I am not sure how to do that.

I have an `actionButton` and depending on the state of that `actionButton` I want to assign a `data.frame` to some `reactiveValues` which then will be processed by some `observers`.

The way I wrote it is like this

```
server.R

myDataFrame <- reactiveValues()

observeEvent(input$myButton, {
    myDataFrame$forProcessing <- some.data.frame
})

observe({
    #do something with myDataFrame$forProcecessing
})
```

However, that crashes. I guess its because `myDataFrame` gets created sort of "empty" which then causes my `observe() #do something...` to crash?!

How would I create the `reactiveValues` properly so that it triggers the `observer()` only when its filled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create the reactive values with the content already there. The solution is to put an empty data frame in the reactive values, and in observe ensure that nothing happens when the data.frame is empty. So:

```
myDataFrame <- reactiveValues(forProcessing = data.frame())
```

and:

```
observe({
    if (nrow(myDataFrame$forProcessing) != 0) {
        #do something with myDataFrame$forProcecessing 
    }
})
```

Comment: Oh really? I do that (creating a `df` with `NULL`) but since I have many dependencies on `myDataFrame$forProcessing` it seemed a bit hacky to always call an `if else` to check for `NULL` at the beginning of each observer...

Comment: The problem is that Shiny needs to identify what kind of reactives there will be. So on the fly adding stuff to it does not work. To limit the `if` statements in the Shiny script, you can make your functions robust to having an empty data input, i.e. they can deal with `data = data.frame()`.

Comment: And in regard to the hackiness, I have not seen the structure of your app,so it is hard to comment on whether or not this is a sub-optimal solution.

Comment: currently I am doing it like this `myDataFrame <- reactiveValues(forProcessing = NULL)` and then `if (is.null(myDataFrame$forProcessing)) {`. That should have the same functionality, right? 
Regarding the hackiness: I am dealing with the creating of many differente `dataframes` which will be processed depending on `ui.R`, the output stored in different `reactiveValues` and the processed again and again. And since I, lets say, do that with seven something  `observers` I thought there might be a way to wrap the `reactiveValues` into something which only triggers when they are `filled` with data.

Comment: That is similar to what I do. I don't know of such functionality, and including the `is.null()` statements does not seem that much overhead to me. You can get rid of the statements by making the operations you do on the `data.frame` correctly work with `data=NULL`, but this might be a lot more code and much harder than simple using the `is.null` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am wondering what might be the advantage of using the `reactiveValues()` when I have to use `if.else` all the time over a `reactive()`?! That does not trigger observers when its empty.

Comment: I'm not sure, if you can get it working with a `reactive` that is also fine for me.